# If $x$ is a nonnegative real number, find the minimum value of $\sqrt{x^2 +4} + \sqrt{x^2 -24x+153}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x$ is a nonnegative real number, then find the minimum value of
$$\sqrt{x^2 +4} + \sqrt{x^2 -24x+153}$$
How can I approach this? Thanks

Comment: Set the derivative to zero.

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E2+%2B4%7D+%2B+%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E2+-24x%2B153%7D%29%27%3D0) gives the derivative is $0$ when $x=\frac{24}{5}$, [python simulation](https://tio.run/##JY3LCsMgEEX3fsUsZ7QJahIIhXyMJdZK6wNxYb7eElwdOBzuzVf9pLjsufTuQ06lQjHxTIG542fC6zTQntg41yBW4lzOGwgYYtIrb0Jty/AsFx8rsuAj4hiZB5C4lpOS8E4FPPh4fziLd67sRkSPr70OR4x6/wM) agrees.

Comment: This question is tagged "algebra-precalculus"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thinking geometrically, you want to minimise the sum of distances from $(x,0)$ to $(0,2)$ and $(x,0)$ to $(12,3)$. Reflect the point $(12,3)$ in the $x$-axis.

The total length of the two line segments from $(0,2)$ to $(x,0)$ and $(x,0)$ to $(12,-3)$ will be smallest when they form a straight line.

Hence the minimum sum of distances is the distance between $(0,2)$ and $(12,-3)$, which is $13$.

Answer (score 3):

**Process 1**: Derivate it to zero

**Process 2**: Using triangle inequality,

Given,$$\sqrt{x^2 +4} + \sqrt{x^2 -24x+153}$$

$$\rightarrow\sqrt{x^2+2^2}+\sqrt{\left(-x+12\right)^2+3^2}\geq \sqrt{\left(x-x+12\right)^2+(2+3)^2} = \sqrt{{12}^2+{5}^2}$$

$$=\sqrt{169}=13$$

I.e, So,

The minimum value is $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{13}$$

Comment: This question is tagged "algebra-precalculus"

Comment: There's a typo in the $\sqrt{12^2+\color{blue}{5}^2}$

Comment: Also in $\sqrt{x^2+4^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the function as
$$\sqrt{x^2+4} + \sqrt{(x-12)^2 + 9}$$
This looks like the sum of distances of a point $(x,0)$ from the points (0,2) and $(12,3)$. This can also be thought of as a light ray originating from $(0,2)$, being reflected from the x-axis and striking the point $(12,9)$. This line of thought allows us to use [Fermat's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_principle) to find the smallest value, which occurs by equating the angles of incidence and reflection. This gives us the minimum value of $13$ at $x = \frac{24}{5}$.

Here's a small animation I came up with:

[image: anim]

Comment: What is AM-GM, please?

Comment: The minimum does not occur when $x=6$; it occurs when $x=24/5$.

Comment: The original answer was wrong. I edited it to give a better answer now.